# EcommerceAPP program method issues

Tags: java

My program is not working. One of the methods I think I did not do right. Can someone please help me fix this program to see what I did wrong. Thank you so much!

The error message i get is failed to compile errors. My method is correct but calling the method is not. The getorder method I think I am not calling it correctly

This is the error I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at 
java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
at ECommerceApp.EcommerceApp.getOrder(EcommerceApp.java:64)
at ECommerceApp.EcommerceApp.main(EcommerceApp.java:14)
```

Here is my program

```
       import java.util.ArrayList;
       import java.util.Random;
       import java.util.Scanner;

      public class EcommerceApp {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Program description
      System.out.println("This program will calculate and display EcommerceApp ");
    // Declaring the variables: types and names
      bannerPrinter();
     ArrayList<String> productCatalog = productsBuilder();
   ****boolean input = getOrder(productCatalog);
   if(getOrder(productCatalog)== true)**** {
        //boolean result = getOrder(productCatalog);
        double price = getPrice();
        double tax = getTax(price);
        double saleTotal = getTotal(price, tax);
        printTotal(saleTotal);
   } 
   else {
       System.out.println("Product does not exit.");
    }

    // Variable initialization: getting the input from the user

    // Calculation
    // Display the result

    //productsBuilder();


}// end of main
// 1.  bannerPrinter
public static void bannerPrinter() {
    System.out.println("******************************************");
    System.out.println("====== Welcome to my eCommerce app! ======");
    System.out.println("******************************************");
    System.out.println();
}// end of method

// end of class
// 2. productsBuilder
public static ArrayList<String> productsBuilder() {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> productsCatalog = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Enter 6 product names: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6;i++) {
        String productName;
        productName = scnr.next();
        productsCatalog.add(productName);
    }
    scnr.close();
    return productsCatalog;
}// end of method
// 3. getOrder
public static boolean getOrder(ArrayList<String> productsCatalog) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < productsCatalog.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(productsCatalog.get(i));
    }
   System.out.println("Enter the product name you want to order: ");
    String input = scnr.next();
    scnr.close();
   for (int i = 0; i < productsCatalog.size();i++){
       if (productsCatalog.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}// end of method
// 4. getPrice
public static double getPrice() {
    double price;
    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    price = randomNumber.nextDouble();
    return price;
}// end of method
// 5. getTax
public static double getTax(double price) {
    double tax;
    tax = price * 0.10;
    return tax;
}// end of method
// 6. getTotal
public static double getTotal(double price, double tax) {
    double saleTotal;
    saleTotal = price + tax;
    return saleTotal;
} // end of method
// 7. printTotal
public static void printTotal(double saleTotal){
    System.out.printf("Your sale total is: $%.2f\n" , saleTotal);
}// end of method
```

}// end of class

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also clearly state what is not working and how you know it's not working, including any error messages, exceptions and stack traces that might occur when you run your program.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper I appreciate you looking out. I just edited the post with more specific detail. I also highlighted the line that is causing an error.

Comment: If the error you get is telling you the program can't be compiled, it should also be telling you why. Please remove the requirements of your assignment, as they are irrelevant to the question, and include the full detail of any and all error messages you get.

Comment: Remove all instances of `scnr.close();`. That closes the input it's bound to, so since you're using two Scanner objects, and you close both, the one you use last won't work.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper Thank you so much! My program seems to be running now. Would that be all the issues you can see?! I appreciate all your help this has been very stressful for me to figure out.